# what do I have to change so that https works?

Tags: node.js

```
const cors = require("cors");
const exp = require("express");
const bp = require("body-parser");
var passport = require("passport");
const https = require('https');
const { connect } = require("mongoose");
var fs = require('fs');
const { success, error } = require("consola");
require('./middlewares/passport');

const { DB, PORT2 } = require("./config");
const options = {
  'key' : fs.readFileSync('./https/key.pem').toString(),
  'cert' : fs.readFileSync('./https/cert.pem').toString()
}
// Initialisation
const app = exp();

// Middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(bp.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());

require("./middlewares/passport")(passport);

app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/users"));
app.use("/api/forum", require("./routes/forumRoute"));
app.use("/api/comments", require("./routes/commentRoute"));

https.createServer(options, app)
  app.listen(PORT2, () =>
    success({ message: `Server : ${PORT2}`, badge: true })
  );
  
const startApp = async () => {
  try {
    await connect(DB, {
      useFindAndModify: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    success({
      message: `Erfolgreich verbunden mit der Datenbank \n${DB}`,
      badge: true
    });

  } catch (err) {
    error({
      message: ` \n${err}`,
      badge: true
    });
    startApp();
  }
};

startApp();
```

I can´t go to https://localhost with port 3000 which is PORT2
I have saved this information in .env file
I created the cert.pem and key.pem with openssl

So what should I change to start the server under https certification?
I used this instruction to create this all:
https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using port 2

Or if you do try not to it’s bad practice

Using port 1 is always less deceptive

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).